# regularity theory for harmonic maps, inquiry

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I'm reading this paper from uhlenbeck & schoen,[a regularity theory for harmonic maps](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.jdg/1214436923), and have some troubles with their notation.

Can you help me out and tell me what they mean by $\pi$ in the proof of lemma 2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the context, I gather that it is capital $\Pi$. The small $\pi$ appearing in the text is most likely a typo (also because 4 lines later the same expression appears with $\Pi$ instead of $\pi$).

Comment: initially i thought the same, but isnt a (double) typo very unlikely in a published paper?

Comment: @augustinsouchy I don't think so. I haven't published anything in a journal (yet), but as far as I know the review process is more like giving the article to other mathematicians in the field to see if it is interesting or not and if it is then just publish it. I don't thing there is a very accurate control of all proofs...

Comment: @augustinsouchy Anyway, just try to finish the proof assuming that $\pi=\Pi$. If it works, very good. If not, then probably $\pi$ means something else ;)

Comment: Having typo in a paper is extremely common. @augustinsouchy

Comment: typo it was :-)